# Why remote image url with HTTP is forced to use HTTPS schema?

Tags: laravel, http, nginx, https, laravel-forge

#### Some Info

I have a Laravel app setup on AWS server using Laravel Forge with nginx web server (this information may be irrelevant).

#### The goal

On one of the pages, I'm trying to serve an image which is loaded from a remote url (third party server) like this:<br>
`style="background-image: url('http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/foo/bar/image.png');"`<br>
This server does not have ssl setup and serves the image over `HTTP` schema.

#### The problem

But when the page is accessed in the browser, it tries to load the image using `HTTPS` schema (don't know why) and because this remote server has all the traffic setup over HTTP, the page keeps loading and ends up with error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` and image not loaded.

#### The evidence

Please take a look at the screenshots from chrome dev tools.

[image]

[image]

I honestly have no idea why the image url is forced to `HTTPS`. Tried to look around the issue but couldn't find much on google and stack overflow.

### Edit

Here are the page response headers:
[image]

Comment: Guessing your site probably has a CSP with `upgrade-insecure-requests` set, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

Comment: @CBroe your suggestion seems relevant. Any work-around to fix this specific server urls to be not re-written?

Comment: Probably none, other than to remove the directive completely. As the MDN says, this applies to _"first-party as well as third-party requests"_ - there is no way to limit this to specific domains, or anything like that.

Comment: @CBroe I confirmed that there are no meta tags used for `upgrade-insecure-requests`. Would this be happening from the server side ? And how to check it?

Comment: Go check the response headers for the main document, and see if `Content-Security-Policy` is in there.

Comment: @CBroe - there is no response received for this url. In chrome dev tools, it says `No data found for resourse with given identifier`.

Comment: However, making a cUrl request from the Terminal, I receive an error: `curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`.

Comment: Not for that image URL, for _your_ main document, that tries to embed this resource.

Comment: @CBroe - I have edited the question body to show the page response headers.

Comment: Weird that there's a "naked" `report-to` in there, that should rather be _part of_ a `Content-Security-Policy` header. But I am guessing this is something you will have to fix somewhere in the Cloudflare settings in this instance.